# How to display image if .jpg .png found on post?

Tags: php, javascript, image, bbcode

The goal is to have a user paste a URL in textarea, and it outputs not a simple text or URL but displays that image from the URL?

```
http://www.thecampussocialite.com/wp-content/uploads/South-park-VS.-Family-Guy.jpg
```

Can this be done? Are there any examples?

Comment: You can do that but use CKEditor..

Answer (score 1):

The textarea is simply not capable of that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a rich text editing control, instead of the basic HTML Text Area tag. Popular options are:

- FCKEditor
- TinyMCE